# Personalized floatstyle

Tags: floats, rules, width

I would like to personalize some floatstyle. Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\floatstyle{ruled}
\newfloat{aff}{!ht}{lex}
\floatname{aff}{Affirmation}

\begin{document}
    \begin{aff}
        \lipsum[5]
    \end{aff}
\end{document}
```

My purpose is to obtain the second example in the image below while I'm currently getting the first example:

[image: float]

To describe what I would like: the same width for the two lines and the word "Affirmation" above it (in bold, sans serif). If possible, I would like this float (it doesn't have to be a float if you have another solution) to have a slightly decreased (and modifiable) text width.

Comment: Is the word "Affirmation" supposed to be at the top of every float, or could this word vary from float to float?

Comment: @Mico It does not matter since I only need one float but I think I managed to get something meeting my expectations using `\newenvironment` instead of `\newfloat`
Should I add how I did it as an answer or should this question be closed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I gather from your comment that this environment needn't be a "float" in the LaTeX sense of the word. If that's the case, it should definitely be implemented via `\newenvironment` rather than via `\newfloat`.

Here's a suggested solution. Note that you can change the width of the environment by altering the width of the `minipage` that's embedded in the `aff` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

% filler text macro:
\newcommand\lips{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, 
   vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. 
   Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna. Donec vehicula 
   augue eu neque.}

\newenvironment{aff}{%
   \bigskip\centering
   \begin{minipage}{0.8\textwidth}
   \textbf{\textsf{Affirmation}}
   \medskip\hrule\medskip}{%
   \medskip\hrule\end{minipage}\par\bigskip}

\begin{document}
\hrule % just to demonstrate width of text block
\begin{aff}
    \lips
\end{aff}

\noindent   
\lips
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it is exactly what I needed. I understood after that it was more convenient to use `\newenvironment`. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @MoebiusCorzer - You're most welcome! Note that I've modified the code of the `aff` environment slightly in the meantime, by moving the `\bigskip` directives *outside* the embedded `minipage` environment. This is useful in case the `aff` environment occurs at the very top or very bottom of a page.

Comment: Nice answer! Thank you so much.